# Twitter4j: Download tweets after a certain tweet/point in time

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

I use twitter4j to get my timeline like this:

```
twitter.getHomeTimeline(new Paging(1,100));
```

How can I get the next 100 tweets?
And in general, is it possible to specify two tweets or two points in time and get the tweets that were posted in between?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you can get the next 100 tweets in your timeline by specifying page 2 and calling `getHomeTimeline` again.

```
Paging paging = new Paging(2, 100);
List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
```

---

You can also specify two tweets (by status id) using `Paging` to get the tweets that were posted in between using the `sinceId` and `maxId` methods.

> since_id: returns elements which id are bigger than the specified id
>   max_id: returns elements which id are smaller than the specified id

For example:

```
Paging paging = new Paging(1, 10).sinceId(258347905419730944L)
                                   .maxId(258348815243960320L);
List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
```

(I had about five tweets in my timeline between the two ids above.  Just click on a tweet on the Twitter web interface and click on the Details link to be taken to the page for that tweet.  Then you can copy the status ID from the URL.)